# mysql compare 2 rows same table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to compare 2 rows and display the same ones.I did browse but was not able to find the right solution.

Table A

```
Count     status         Division
20          A               1
30          B               2
10          c               1
12          z               1
```

From the above table I want to display whose division is same.

```
Count     status         Division
20          A               1
10          c               1
12          z               1
```

Comment: Please format output. Its difficult to understand what you need

Comment: `SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE division=_____`-Display information where division = something OR `SELECT COUNT(*), division FROM TableName GROUP BY division`- Display number of records for each division

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select * from TableA 
Group By Division 
Having Count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from TableA
Group By Division 
having Count(*) = 1
```

Comment: You should flesh out your answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Here i used case statement , it worked for me

select CompanyCode  ,'Commission Pec',  Year
,sum(case  when CommissionType='Commission Recevied' then JAN else 0 end)/sum(case when CommissionType='Net Payments from WM' and isnull(JAN,0)<>0 then JAN else 1  end) 
 from Commission_Consolidate

group by CompanyCode,Year

end